# Moving element to specific css coordinates (top and left) not working using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move a HTML element (a puzzle piece) back to its original position on the screen after a dragEnd event, if the element is not inside a specified target zone.

I using a javascript object to represent the puzzle piece. The object contains the starting x and y for the element as well as a reference to the element itself (along with some other information). The code is below.

```
function dragEnd(e) {

    if(selectedPiece.ele.id === "correctPiece" && selectedPiece.distanceVector < 30){
        window.alert("Game End");
    }
    else{

        console.log("returning piece: ", selectedPiece.ele.id);
        console.log("to point ", selectedPiece.startX, selectedPiece.startY);
        selectedPiece.ele.style.position = "absolute";
        selectedPiece.ele.style.left = selectedPiece.startX;
        selectedPiece.ele.style.top = selectedPiece.startY;
        
    }
    active = false;
}
```

Still when I drop the piece it stays wherever it was dropped.

When I look at the console it shows the element id and identifies the correct startX and startY properties. I have also tried appending "px" to the startX and startY with no luck.

Any help appreciated thanks :)

Comment: Try with a hard-coded value to see if it works. selectedPiece.ele.style.left = "0px" selectedPiece.ele.style.top = "0px"

Comment: try wrapping them also in a timeout if it works.

Comment: I have tried hard coding the values and the pieces ends up moving but not to the x,y position that has been coded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried hard coding the values and the pieces ends up moving but not to the x,y position that has been coded

Then, try this:

```
    selectedPiece.ele.style.left = selectedPiece.startX + "px";
    selectedPiece.ele.style.top = selectedPiece.startY + "px";
```

> but not to the x,y position that has been coded

Secondly, make sure you understand how CSS `absolute` works. From [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute_positioning):

> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not static).

Try making dragged element's immediate parent's position `relative`.

Comment: The parent elements are now set to relative and are moving but still not in the expected way. I'm wondering if the problem is related to the way I am obtaining the startX and startY. In the console it shows, in one case that the start position was (831, 720) and correctly attempts to move it to this position, but when I print out the objects currentX and currentY it ends at (959,900). To obtain these coordinates I am using element.getBoundingClientRect() and getting the X and Y from this.

Comment: @Ciaran Muir `getBoundingClientRect()` gives top-left coordinates of the element. You might want to find the center of the element. Stackoverflow questions should focus on one problem only. I think you should ask a new question for that problem. Hope this helps!